# What happens to a target you are grabbing when you are knocked prone?

Tags: dnd-4e, prone, grapple

One of my PCs grabbed someone with a garrote and was knocked prone shortly afterwards. What would happen to the grabbed target? Would he be let go (it was a human), would he get knocked prone as well (being grabbed) or something completely different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nothing would happen.**

The [grabbed](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=405) condition ends when

- The attacker and the target are separated by more squares than the grabber has reach (usually by forced movement)
- The target succeeds on an [escape](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=328) check
- The attacker is subject to an effect that prevents free actions.

The attacker (or the target) going [prone](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=141) does not meet any of these clauses and would have no effect directly.

It may seem "realistic" to overrule this, especially with a garrote, but that would be a house rule and could lead to unintended consequences.  Considering that dropping prone is a minor action, this would allow the attacker to cause the target to go prone for just a minor action with no attack roll required.

Comment: Yeah. It did seem kinda unlikely that he crawled around garroting someone, but rules are rules

Comment: @jason - yes they are.  My least favorite is the mismatch between what I think Immobilized should mean, and the actual effects in the game :)